# Portable admin-less cross-compiling 2D game developing program?

Tags: windows-7, c++, cross-platform, portable, game-development

I've worked with so many game developing programs which work and don't work. Some have limitations, some worked all until once, some can't export to some platforms, some cost too much, …

So far, I've been using these:

- **Game Maker**: outdated and detected by Norton
- **Game Maker Studio**: too expensive for cross-platform! I bought the standard version, but then realized I need Professional and then Export Modules on top of that
- **Multimedia Fusion series**: same
- **ENIGMA/LateralGM**: awesome and promising, but some functions don't work, no enough tutorials, missing documentation on some functions, instance control functions not fully implemented, admin privileges required to compile
- **GameDevelop**: can't export to Android and as much as I remember, it requires admin too as well.
- **XNA**: requires Visual Studio which can't be portable, no Android or Linux.
- **Allegro**: no Android, just coding
- **SFML**: no Android, just coding, didn't get it to work on Visual Studio (and yes, I followed everything about the getting started tutorial thing)
- **Unreal Engine**: I'm not good at modelling.
- **Unity**: too difficult. Android apps allocate 100MB.

I mostly like Game Maker Studio because it's graphical, has Intellisense in coding, full offline documentation, always some updates. The only problem about it is that it costs $500!

So what I need to know is if there is a program with these specifications:

1. If it's about coding, **it must be C++**. If it's scripting, it must be C++ish. Example is Game Maker Studio.
2. Must have instance control, **instance pointers**, instance choice **iteration**, **object inheritance** …
3. **Collision detection** from up, down, left, right, must be **specific**!
   This situation is hardly solvable in MMF2 series. Game Maker Studio can do it.
4. Must have a **detailed user-friendly documentation**.
5. Must have a **good community** so I can ask a question or search for solutions.
   Game Maker Studio's community is a great example.
6. Must be **portable**! **No admin rights** should be required!
   This means that I can put it on my USB stick and plug it into any school or library computer **without administrator rights** required for the **compiler** to work.
7. If shareware, it must **not be over $80** and must have **trial version** with **full export features** so I can see if it works for me.
8. **Must not be detected as virus** or trojan by Norton.
   Because some of my friends have Norton, they couldn't run my Game Maker games. This can be a big problem if I would sell my games.
9. Must be **graphical** and **toolchained**.
   I don't want to make games by only typing code and nothing else. I need an IDE with a **level/room editor**. A click on the compile button should compile the game.
10. Must be **runnable** on Windows 7 Home Premium, and ideally also on Slacko Puppy Linux and Raspberry Pi (if possible).
11. Must **export for these platforms**:

    - Windows 7
    - Puppy Linux
    - Ubuntu
    - Android 4.x
    - Raspberry Pi (if possible)
    - Mac and iOS (if possible)
12. Game's EXE must be able to **load and save INI and binary files**. Simple file I/O, file and folder management.
    SDL is a perfect example on Android and Windows.
13. Game's EXE must be able to **load sprites** (images) **from external files** while not losing the initial sprites or the previously loaded ones.
    This is a problem in MMF2 and therefore it's impossible to make online avatar-customizing game.
14. Game's EXE must be able to **load WAV sounds**.
15. Game's EXE must be able to **recolor sprites**.
16. Must **compile one EXE** with all its elements.
    Can have DLLs in the same folder, but mustn't require anything from the system.
    Every portable game is an example.
17. Game's EXE must be able to **remap keys/buttons** and/or recognize the inputs.
    All games have the feature where you can **change your controls**.
18. Executable should be able to host/join a game for **online play** on a specific **IP address and port** (like Minecraft does in *server.properties*).

I might be nitpicking, but take a look at games like Super Mario Bros X or Super Mario War.
They're both portable, they both load everything externally while their code is compiled inside the EXE. Both games can remap keys and use joypads.

Is there a program that fits my needs?

Comment: Did you manage to find a good framework?

Comment: I found SDL2, but there's no other IDE  besides Visual Studio.

Comment: Actually, I could use compiler or Code Blocks. So no other IDE. But I'm happy with this so far

Comment: So the tool must run on Windows 7 *and* Slacko Puppy Linux (*and* possibly Raspberry Pi), or is only one of these platforms sufficient?

Comment: I changed my mind when I realized I'm too requiring. Windows 7 is a must. I don't have a rpi, but I'm thinking of getting it if it will be my game developing portable device

Comment: It's very difficult to cross-compile a program to both a desktop platform and a mobile platform because they use different frameworks. You would need to create your own wrapper if you wanted to develop for Android, and even then, Apple may not allow you to do this for iOS. If anything, you should cover one platform first, then port your game to the other platform. Also, Ubuntu and Puppy Linux are not different platforms. You are compiling essentially to the same target (x86 ELF). For Raspberry Pi, you compile to ARM. In this case, your project is too complicated to be created automagically.

Comment: How did Terraria succeed?

Comment: And also. I found SDL2. SuperTux has a version for Android, Windows and Linux because it's made using SDL. However, there's no graphical IDE

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [pyGame](http://www.pygame.org/), the major points it doesn't satisfy is it isn't C++ it is [python](http://www.python.org) and it doesn't compile to exe.  You can use it portably, (windows via [portable python](http://portablepython.com) - includes pygame as one of the libraries), running from source on other platforms - most Android machines have python installed, ditto OS-X and it is the default language for RaspberryPi.

There is an [Adroid](http://pygame.renpy.org/) port of a subset of the functionality and depending on the type of games you are developing you will often find frameworks with graphical editors, e.g. [fabula](http://www.pygame.org/project-fabula-1746-3782.html) for adventure, role-playing & strategy games.

Loading configurations, sprites, images, etc. are all handled by the python libraries.

All the above is Free, (Gratis), and Open Source, (FOSS).

Python is possibly one of the easier programming languages to learn and there are a lot of resources available, many free.

Comment: If it is GPL and requiring me to release source code, then no. Can it somehow bundle its default executable with an emulator into one exe?

Comment: It is LGPL so no it is not - you can bundle your application libraries into a zip file, possibly with some encryption, and just have a launcher as a .py file.

Comment: Aren't stuff compiled, but just interpreted in that archive?

Comment: Byte compiled, (.pyo), or source files, (.py), can be in there - usually .pyo

Comment: Excellent! But before I approve this answer, I have to test the tool.

Comment: Have Fun @Foxcat385!

Comment: @Foxcat385 Actually, scripts can be made into executables using [cxFreeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Can that include all files?

Comment: source files, I mean

Comment: Basically for each program name you have a small file which just invokes python, (portable python for windows), and loads the zipimporter then all the sources live inside the zip, (which does not have to actually be called .zip).

Comment: I'm having trouble installing pygame. It says "No module named 'pygame'" in Python shell.

Comment: Download the source package and unzip it then from the command line cd to the place you unzipped it and type `python setup.py install` - Make sure that you use the python that you need it to work with!

Comment: I worked on Python a bit and didn't like the language. Everything has to be explicit and it doesn't have pointers like C. It uses garbage collector instead of new and delete only. However, I found something else. Oxygin Engine.